# Structuring a model in Optaplanner: basic

Tags: optaplanner

I am fascinated with Optaplanner and am trying to learn it by constructing examples.  I would be grateful for any tips that could help me structure this problem.

The problem domain has

- Performers who perform in classes of performance: one performer may perform in several classes
- Venues in which the performers perform
- Time slots in which the performers perform
- Competitions in which there are performers performing in their classes in a set of venues
- Which performers will perform in which class is known ahead of time
- Each performance takes a fixed amount of time
- There are no constraints on the size of a class: classes are open to all comers, but the list of performers and their requested classes is fixed at the beginning of the model run

The objectives and constraints are:

1. Schedule the performances in a competition to take the least amount of elapsed time (i.e. try to make full use of multiple venues);
2. A class must start and finish in the same venue, but any class can use any venue;
3. Once a class starts in a venue, it has exclusive use of the venue until it finishes;
4. Only one performer can perform in a given venue in a given time slot;
5. A performer cannot be in two different venues at the same time;
6. Every performer must be permitted to perform in each class that they request;
7. Order of performance in a class doesn't matter;
8. A performer must have at least "n" time slots between performances;
9. It is desirable to avoid dead time-slots in a venue;
10. An individual performance takes  exactly "m"  minutes irrespective of class, performer or venue;
11. If a class has n performers and each performance takes m minutes, a class will continue in its assigned venue from its assigned starting time until n * m minutes later (plus x * m if there are x dead time slots);
12. In a typical problem, there might be 4 venues, 15 classes and 200 performers, with large variance in the size of the classes (from 1 to 30 or more performers in each class).

My first thought was to schedule the classes to venues and starting time-slots first, then rearrange the order of performances if doing so is necessary to resolve conflicts.  Only if conflicts can't be resolved by changing the order of performances in a class can the assignment of classes to venues or starting times change.

What's not clear to me is how to handle the shuffling of performer/time-slot/venue mappings and then revert to shuffling class/venue/start-time mappings if there remain conflicts.

The first part of the problem (deciding an initial class to venue/start-time) seems like simple bin-packing.  I'm not sure if that's the best time to consider reordering performances, however.

Any assistance would be gratefully received.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the docs section [4.3.1. Is This Class a Problem Fact or Planning Entity?](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#isThisClassAProblemFactOrPlanningEntity). It contains a number of guidelines on how to design a good domain model.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet Thank you very much for taking the time to read my question and comment.